# Am trying to convert dataurl into image but it is not working for svg files

Tags: java

```
//read image
try{
  // f = new File("G:\\Image\\Taj.jpg"); //image file path
  URL url = new URL("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/582092645c2f894f0cf8f02f/58481fbed43b9934653a9440_Analytiks%20en-01.jpg");

  image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  image = ImageIO.read(url);
  System.out.println("Reading complete.");
}catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Error: "+e);
}

//write image
try{
  f = new File("G:\\Image\\abc.jpg");  //output file path
  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
  System.out.println("Writing complete.");
}catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Error: "+e);`
}
```

Comment: URL url = new URL("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/582092645c2f894f0cf8f02f/58481fbed43b9934653a9440_Analytiks%20en-01.jpg");

      image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Comment: this is first line of this program sry i missed

Comment: you can edit your post and add the missing part instead of comments

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the necessary information in the question. The comments are not a place for code. Also add to the question exactly what your trouble is, if there are any errors, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.